# Reading data from Firebase - Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I would like to change `String` to something else in order to read data from firebase.

I have the following code:

```
enum Answers{GS,FB}

String _value = ''; //Probably, String should be changed. 

void _setValue(String value) => setState(() => _value = value); ////Probably, String should be changed.

Future kaleciSec(BuildContext context) async {
    switch(
    await showDialog(
...
...
                           StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('GS').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return Center (child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        return Column(

                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
            onTap: (){Navigator.pop(context, Answers.GS);}, //selecting GS.
            title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['kaleci1'], //showing data from DB

             ),
          ),
           Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey,),

                      ListTile(
            onTap: (){Navigator.pop(context, Answers.FB);},
            title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['kaleci2'],
             ),

          ],
        );


      },
    ),      
                     ],
                     ),
    )
    )    


               {
      case Answers.GS:
      _setValue('GS'); //I would like connect database here.
      break;
      case Answers.FB:
      _setValue('FB'); //I would like connect database here.
      break;

    }
```

My code works without an error. But, I need to show what is selected. Basically, I would like to change `_setValue('GS');` to something like `_setValue(snapshot.data.documents[0]['kaleci1']);` this. Please help me!

I stick on this issue for a few days.

Comment: Since you're already using the data from the document in `title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[0]['kaleci2'],`, what is keeping you from using it in the call to `_setValue()`?

Comment: User will choose either kaleci1 or kaleci2. I would like to track which one is choosen. In this case, am I wrong with this coding?

Comment: OK. So for that you'll create a variable to hold what the user selected (say `selected = 'kaleci1'`), and then use that when accessing the data from the document (`snapshot.data.documents[0][selected]`).

Comment: I included `var selected = 'kaleci1';` and updated `snapshot.data.documents[0][selected]`. Then, `_setValue(selected);`. But, when I select kaleci1, it's written **kaleci1**. I would like show the data, say kaleci1 is **Frank**. It should show Frank, not kaleci1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is showing "kaleci1", because the `_setValue(selected)`, is only reading the value of the variable and not the valeu from the database.

For you to return the value there, you would need to return the value of the database and add it to a new (or the same variable), so you can use in the `_setValue()` function.

I believe the code should be something like this:

```
enum Answers{GS,FB}

String _value = ''; //Probably, String should be changed. 

var selected = 'kaleci1';
var valueDB;

void _setValue(String value) => setState(() => _value = value); ////Probably, String should be changed.

Future kaleciSec(BuildContext context) async {
    switch(
    await showDialog(
...
...
                           StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('GS').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData) return Center (child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        return Column(

                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
                      ListTile(
            onTap: (){Navigator.pop(context, Answers.GS);}, //selecting GS.
            title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[0][selected], //showing data from DB
            valueDB = snapshot.data.documents[0][selected]
             ),
          ),
           Divider(
                    color: Colors.grey,),

                      ListTile(
            onTap: (){Navigator.pop(context, Answers.FB);},
            title: Text(snapshot.data.documents[0][selected],
            valueDB = snapshot.data.documents[0][selected]
             ),

          ],
        );


      },
    ),      
                     ],
                     ),
    )
    )    


               {
      case Answers.GS:
      _setValue(valueDB); //I would like connect database here.
      break;
      case Answers.FB:
      _setValue(valueDB); //I would like connect database here.
      break;

    }
```

Please, let me know how that goes!